# Android method that adds time to a list runs successfully on Genymotion, but not on my phone

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I'm developing an Android app, I have this method that create a list of time.
When I'm running it on `Genymotion` (Nexus4, 4.3) it works without problem.
But when I run it on my `Nexus 4` phone (running 4.4.2), it failed to create the list I want.

The code is here.

```
public void createTimes() {

        times.clear();

        Calendar startTime = Calendar.getInstance();
        startTime.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 8);
        startTime.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 30);

        Calendar endTime = Calendar.getInstance();
        endTime.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 9);
        endTime.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 30);

        Calendar sixOClock = Calendar.getInstance();
        sixOClock.set(Calendar.HOUR, 6);

        while (startTime.compareTo(sixOClock) < 0) {

            String timeString = timeFormat.format(startTime.getTime()) + " - "
                    + timeFormat.format(endTime.getTime());

            times.add(timeString);

            startTime.add(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 1);

            endTime.add(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 1);

        }

    }
```

The result should be like this

```
8:30 AM - 9:30 AM
9:30 AM - 10:30 AM
10:30 AM - 11:30 AM
11:30 AM - 0:30 PM
0:30 PM - 1:30 PM
1:30 PM - 2:30 PM
2:30 PM - 3:30 PM
3:30 PM - 4:30 PM
4:30 PM - 5:30 PM
5:30 PM - 6:30 PM
```

Anyone knows what's the problem? Thanks.

**Edit:**
Umm... I think I know what's the problem.
I simply changed

```
sixOClock.set(Calendar.HOUR, 6);
```

to

```
sixOClock.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 18);
```

and it works on my phone now.
It's strange cause this problem doesn't occur when I'm running on `genymotion`.

Comment: You would have to elaborate on *failed to create the list I want*. Any exceptions which you get or just a broken UX?